# Ember Changest –– cannot return field to original value

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've run into an issue using ember-changeset and ember-changeset-validations –– I have form fields that I am able to change to a new value, but once changed, I am unable to reset them to their original value.

This line from the set property method seems to be the problem somehow ––the it seems that my object should be returning yes that it does have the key but it is returning false:

```
} else if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
```

For example I start with value:

Start value: Canada
Change to: Burundi - ok
Change to: Canad -- unable to add final "a" -– when submitted, form will be submitted with value of "Canad" instead of "Canada"....

I assume this is not an issue with ember-changeset but an issue either with something I am doing wrong and/or something about my objects (JSON-API from Ember Data).

Have tried this in three different projects, trying to eliminate all possible external sources of trouble and have yet to find a solution.

Comment: Wondering if it has to do with quoted object keys –– when I turn on Mirage, I have no problem. When I use JSON-API from actual Phoenix or Rails API, the problem kicks in.

Comment: I'm finding that key in obj returns true, but obj.hasOwnProperty(key) returns false, still not sure if this is an issue in ember-changeset, or on my end.

Comment: Looking to me now like it may be an issue with ember-changeset related to ember data models, that arose with release 1.2.2, where the obj.hasOwnProperty(key) code check was introduced.